# SQL Server is not using any index when querying on a HierarchyId column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchy

I've got some hierarchical data which I'm attempting to store using the `hierarchyid` datatype of SQL Server. Data size is a few hundred thousand rows, with items having only a few children (a shallow and wide dataset).

I'm having some problems when querying for an item and its children. The correct way seems to be to use the `IsDescendantOf` function.

I've used the below script to populate some sample data, which is ~500k rows, each with no children.

```
CREATE TABLE TestData 
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
    HierarchyValue hierarchyid PRIMARY KEY
)
go

set identity_insert TestData on

insert into TestData (ID, HierarchyValue) values (0,'/')

insert into TestData (ID, HierarchyValue)
   select top 500000 
       row_number() over(order by t1.number) as number, 
       '/' + cast(row_number() over(order by t1.number)as varchar(10)) +'/'
   from   
       master..spt_values t1 
   cross join 
       master..spt_values t2

set identity_insert TestData off  

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX HierarchyValueIndex 
ON dbo.TestData(HierarchyValue ASC)
```

I'm then running the following query to find the children of the item `0x58`

```
 select *
 from TestData
 where HierarchyValue.IsDescendantOf(0x58) = 1
```

I get exactly one result (as expected), but the query is scanning over all the rows in the table, which is rather slow (See images below). Is this type of query indexable?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting: trying to replicate this on SQL Server **2012**, I get a `Clustered Index Seek` (as you probably hoped for). Is that your **actual** or an **estimated** execution plan?

Comment: This is the actual execution plan. The estimated execution plan shows an index seek as well.

Comment: Strange that it would list `Estimated Number of Rows = 500001` .... something's funky here (I get an estimated - and actual - number of rows of 1). Is this somehow the execution plan for the *second* query (that builds up the lower half of the result pane) ?!?!?!?

Comment: It's definitely the correct query. I flipped `set statsitics profile off` to remove the detailed result information, and still got 500001 estimated/actual rows.

I also ran the same query on an instance of SQL Server 2014, and got  an index seek. Looks like this is specific to 2008.

Comment: Did you ever find out why the query with IsDescendantOf() is not using HierarchyValueIndex?

Comment: I believe I chalked it up to a bug in Sql Server 2008. Ended up upgrading our SQL Server instance (to 2012 I think), which fixed the issue.